# Hibernate / JPA Why many-to-many join column id is false?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

to-many tables mapped like this :

Resume.java :

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
 @JsonIgnore
   @JoinTable(
           name = "resume_skills", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resume_id"))
 private List<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<Skill>();


 public void addSkill(Skill skill) {
     skills.add(skill);
     skill.getResumes().add(this);
 }
```

Skill.java

```
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="skills")
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Resume> resumes;
```

I do this :

```
Resume resumeToAdd = new Resume(resume.getGithubAdress(),
            resume.getLinkedinAdress(),
            resume.getCoverLetter(),
            resume.getPicture(),
            employee
            );
    
    resumeDao.save(resumeToAdd);
    
    Skill skill = skillService.findById(1).getData();
    System.out.println(skill);
    resumeToAdd.addSkill(skill);
    resumeDao.save(resumeToAdd);
```

But it occurs an error, for example it added a Resume with id 60 and it's trying to add mapping with skill id 60 But it cant because there is  no skill in database with id of 60, it should be 1. What did i miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you mixed up the order of the mapping. It should be this:

```
@JoinTable(
       name = "resume_skills", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resume_id"), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id"))
```